# MYSQL SELECT query with WHERE not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, where-clause

The data in my database has a list of names and each name has an ID. I am trying to make a simple search to pull the persons ID when the name matches the searched name.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& empty($_POST['personName'])==FALSE ){
    $name=$_POST['personName'];

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        echo "No numeric characters allowed";   
    }else{
        include('connect.php');
        if($con==false){
        }else if ($con==true){
            $cleanName=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
            $getPersonID="SELECT person_ID FROM person WHERE Name='$cleanName'";
            $resultGetPersonID=mysqli_query($con,$getPersonID)or die(mysqli_error($con));
            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultGetPersonID)>0){
                echo "query sucessrful";
            }else{
                echo "query failed";
            }

        }
    }

}else{
    echo "Data entered wrong";
}
```

html

```
     <div class="searchBox">
    <form action="getPerson.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input id='personName' type="text" name="personName" >&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search" name="submit">

   </form>  
  </div>
```

[Person Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FCJx.png)

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oYDj.png)

Comment: We need the table structure in order to help.  Also, where is $clearName initialized?

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of things like `$x==false`. Most methods are designed to return truthful values so you can do `if ($con)` without all the fuss.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: if you run `WHERE Name='Test'` and it works, then something failed.

Comment: well, someone popped an answer just; see that.

Comment: Are you entering a valid name in the screen?

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($_POST)` right at the top of the script  and post that in your question as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the ids for names which `match` the input then you might want to try that with `like` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT person_ID FROM person WHERE Name like %<input>%
```

for case insensitive matching, try using `lower` function and pass the name in lower case, g.g:

```
SELECT person_ID FROM person WHERE lower(Name) like %<input>%
```

Comment: What needs to be put in ''? Does the %<input>%?

Comment: `$cleanName` needs to be put in place of <input>

Comment: May I ask why it works? Or why a simple = to the input does not work?

Comment: `=` performs the exact matching whereas `like` performs partial matching. E.g. if I type `Dar`, `=` will only bring up names which completely match `Dar`, and not `Darshan`.